# Matlab: separate connected components

Tags: matlab, image-processing, watershed, connected-components

I was working on my image processing problem with detecting coins.

I have some images like this one here:
[image: Binary components]

and wanted to separate the falsely connected coins.
We already tried the watershed method as stated on the MATLAB-Homepage:

- [the-watershed-transform-strategies-for-image-segmentation.html](http://de.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/the-watershed-transform-strategies-for-image-segmentation.html)

especially since the first example is exactly our problem.

But instead we get a somehow very messed up separation as you can see here:

[image]

We already extracted the area of the coin using the `regionprops` Extrema parameter and casting the watershed only on the needed area.

I'd appreciate any help with the problem or even another method of getting it separated.

Comment: This problem can be solved simply by using the h-minima transform (`imhmin`) or other form of smoothing on the distance image, before applying the watershed operator. The 3rd example in the linked tutorial page does exactly this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, I can also suggest the [Circular Hough Transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) through `imfindcircles`.  However, this requires at least version R2012a, so if you don't have it, this won't work.

For the sake of completeness, I'll assume you have it.  This is a good method if you want to leave the image untouched.  If you don't know what the [Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) is, it is a method for finding straight lines in an image.  The **circular** Hough Transform is a special case that aims to find circles in the image.

The added advantage of the circular Hough Transform is that it is able to detect partial circles in an image.  This means that those regions in your image that are connected, we can detect them as separate circles.  How you'd call `imfindcircles` is in the following fashion:

```
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles(A, radiusRange);
```

`A` would be your binary image of objects, and `radiusRange` is a two-element array that specifies the minimum and maximum radii of the circles you want to detect in your image.  The outputs are:

- `centers`: A `N x 2` array that tells you the `(x,y)` co-ordinates of each centre of a circle that is detected in the image - `x` being the column and `y` being the row.
- `radii`: For each corresponding centre detected, this also gives the radius of each circle detected.  This is a `N x 1` array.

There are additional parameters to `imfindcircles` that you may find useful, such as the `Sensitivity`.  A higher sensitivity means that it is able to detect circular shapes that are more non-uniform, such as what you are showing in your image.  They aren't perfect circles, but they are round shapes.  The default sensitivity is 0.85.  I set it to 0.9 to get good results.  Also, playing around with your image, I found that the radii ranged from 50 pixels to 150 pixels.  Therefore, I did this:

```
im = im2bw(imread('http://dennlinger.bplaced.net/t06-4.jpg'));
[centers,radii] = imfindcircles(im, [50 150], 'Sensitivity', 0.9);
```

The first line of code reads in your image directly from StackOverflow.  I also convert this to `logical` or true black and white as the image you uploaded is of type `uint8`.  This image is stored in `im`.  Next, we call `imfindcircles` in the method that we described.

Now, if we want to visualize the detected circles, simply use `imshow` to show your image, then use the [`viscircles`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/viscircles.html) to draw the circles in the image.

```
imshow(im);
viscircles(centers, radii, 'DrawBackgroundCircle', false);
```

`viscircles` by default draws the circles with a white background over the contour.   I want to disable this because your image has white circles and I don't want to show false contouring.  This is what I get with the above code:

[image]

Therefore, what you can take away from this is the `centers` and `radii` variables.  `centers` will give you the centre of each detected circle while `radii` will tell you what the radii is for each circle.

---

Now, if you want to simulate what `regionprops` is doing, we can iterate through all of the detected circles and physically draw them onto a 2D map where each circle would be labeled by an ID number.  As such, we can do something like this:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(im,2), 1:size(im,1));
IDs = zeros(size(im));
for idx = 1 : numel(radii)
    r = radii(idx);
    cen = centers(idx,:);

    loc = (X - cen(1)).^2 + (Y - cen(2)).^2 <= r^2;
    IDs(loc) = idx;
end
```

We first define a rectangular grid of points using [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and initialize an IDs array of all zeroes that is the same size as the image.  Next, for each pair of radii and centres for each circle, we define a circle that is centered at this point that extends out for the given radius.  We then use these as locations into the IDs array and set it to a unique ID for that particular circle.  The result of `IDs` will be that which resembles the output of [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html).  As such, if you want to extract the locations of where the `idx` circle is, you would do:

```
cir = IDs == idx;
```

For demonstration purposes, this is what the IDs array looks like once we scale the IDs such that it fits within a `[0-255]` range for visibility:

```
imshow(IDs, []);
```

[image]

Therefore, each shaded circle of a different shade of gray denotes a unique circle that was detected with `imfindcircles`.

However, the shades of gray are probably a bit ambiguous for certain coins as this blends into the background.  Another way that we could visualize this is to apply a different colour map to the IDs array.  We can try using the `cool` colour map, with the total number of colours to be the number of unique circles + 1 for the background.  Therefore, we can do something like this:

```
cmap = cool(numel(radii) + 1);
RGB = ind2rgb(IDs, cmap);
imshow(RGB);
```

The above code will create a colour map such that each circle gets mapped to a unique colour in the `cool` colour map.  The next line applies a mapping where each ID gets associated with a colour with [`ind2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html) and we finally show the image.

This is what we get:

[image]

Comment: imfindcircles is part of the Image Processing Toolbox.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I found the function and I think it's a pretty elegant way. One simpler question still remains: I now want to label the connected components, so I would like to add all pixels of a circle to one connected component. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I should add, that I (for now) simply add all white areas larger than my margin to the connected components (bwconncomp), and simply want to split/edit my falsely recognized coins.

Comment: @AshishUthama doh! I meant to say that actually. Thanks!

Comment: @dennlinger that will require an edit that I can't do right now. On my way to work. I'll edit soon!

Comment: @dennlinger - Done.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: the following solution is more adequate to scenarios where one does not require fitting the exact circumferences, although simple heuristics could be used to approximate the radii of the coins in the original image based on the centers found in the eroded one.*

Assuming you have access to the Image Processing toolbox, try `imerode` on your original black and white image. It will apply an erosion morphological operator to your image. In fact, the [Matlab webpage with the documentation of that function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imerode.html) has an example strikingly similar to your problem/image and they use a disk structure.

Run the following code (based on the example linked above) assuming the image you submitted is called `ima.jpg` and is local to the code:

```
ima=imread('ima.jpg');
se = strel('disk',50);
eroded = imerode(ima,se);
imshow(eroded)
```

and you will see the image that follows as output. After you do this, you can use `bwlabel` to label the connected components and compute whatever properties you may want, for example, count the number of coins or detect their centers.

[image]

Comment: first: thanks for the quick answer. We already experimented a bit with the imerode/imdilate function, yet i am still not entirely sure if it suits my case, since it seems that i would only get those pixels into my connected components which are still white after the imerode, right? So technically i would get, say 70% of what really was a white dot, or am i wrong? I should have specified that I need most of the pixels, since I want to automatically discern different types of coins.

Comment: Yes, you did not specify you needed the pixels in the original question. Do you mind if I ask why you need most of the pixels? This operator seems to be roughly preserving the relative areas between coins, so you could estimate the general shrinkage ratio based on knowing how much one of the coins shrunk from the original to the eroded image (or average it over a few coins to get a smooth estimation), and then scaling the shrunk connected components area by that ratio.

Comment: However, since you have `imfindcircles` available, you may want to stick to the other solution and work in the polar space.

Comment: We actually tried your method and came up with sort of the same idea, yet we got a pretty wide shrink ratio (from ~2.5-4.5, depending on the coins), but I still appreciate your answer!